Integration React Native into Android Project
I implemented React Native into an existing native Android project. It's running fine, but the Metro server isn't connecting with the app, and the automatic reload isn't working. I can only update the React Native part by generating a new index.android.bundle and running the app again in Android Studio.
Does anyone have any ideas or has done something similar that could help me out?
React Native was configured on root of project.
app (android kotlin project)
node_modules
index.js (entry file react native)
metro.config.js
react.native.config.js

React Native config:
module.exports = {
  project: {
    android: {
      sourceDir: '.',
    },
  },
}


Metro config:
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname));


the react native version is 0.73.11
